# What is "emacs load-path"?

Tags: emacs, elisp

I want to change my `emacs` source code theme. They say in emacswiki that I have to add the .el file in a directory in my load-path, but what is my load-path? And how do I access it?

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at the Load Path page on emacswiki: http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LoadPath

Basically, you want to add the directory like so:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/emacs-load-path")
```

Comment: i know. but how do a do that. must i tipe this into the command bar M-x or what? i still new to emacs and linux soo

Comment: Create a file called `.emacs` in your home directory and put the code in there. To test it, put your cursor after the last parentheses and press `C-x e` or restart emacs. http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html

Comment: Ruben Van St Aden: This other Q&A will probably prove helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545437/how-to-disable-the-beep-in-emacs-on-windows