# How to config gnu emacs on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, emacs, gnu, xemacs

I use gnu emacs on Mac OS X, but I can't find the .emacs.

And I create ~\.emacs, but it doesn't work. How can I config my emacs?

Comment: Try looking for `~/.emacs`.

Comment: See [this question](http://superuser.com/q/73458/4542) for some hints on how to find the file.

Comment: Also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545437/how-to-disable-the-beep-in-emacs-on-windows/10545955#10545955

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The recommended practice these days is to create a folder called `.emacs.d`, then put a file called `init.el` in there. Emacs will load this file on startup.

```
cd
mkdir .emacs.d
cd .emacs.d
touch init.el
```

This `.emacs.d` folder is where Emacs will place temporary files, packages, etc, that you would not want polluting your home folder.

If you're new to emacs and just want to get up-and-running, consider downloading one of the existing emacs configurations on github and tweaking that:

- [Prelude](https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude)
- [Starter Kit](https://github.com/technomancy/emacs-starter-kit)