# Where do I change the syntax highlighting of Emacs?

Tags: emacs

I've been told to put a file called NAME.el in my home directory and to add `(load "~/.NAME") ;;` to the Emacs configuration file .emacs.

(1) Where is this configuration file?

(2) Can I insert this line of code anywhere?

(3) Just out of interest, why is this line of code in parenthesis?

Note: I don't want to know how Emacs works! I just want to change some colours.

Comment: You can start reading the manual here `https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html`.

Comment: @abo-abo I did try that, but it's incomprehensible to me :(

Comment: (1) `~/.emacs` (2) yes, usually (3) because it's LISP syntax, you can look it up on Wikipedia.

Comment: Also, it should be `(load "~/NAME")`, i.e. without the dot

Comment: Create a file called `init.el` and put it inside the hidden folder in your home directory labeled `.emacs.d`.  The `.emacs.d` folder is created automatically when you open Emacs.  Hidden items in the Finder.app of OSX can be revealed with `Command+Shift+period`.   Then put something simple inside the `init.el` file, like `(defun hello-world () (interactive) (message "My name is User 17670.")) (global-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'hello-world)`  Now restart Emacs and press the F5 key and you should see a message at the bottom of your screen.  Be prepared to spend an *enormous* amount of time learning.

Comment: @abo-abo is 100% correct. You must make a minimal effort to learn the basics. This question risks being closed because minimal knowledge isn't demonstrated.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html.

Comment: @lawlist What am I supposed to do with the `NAME.el` file?

Comment: User 17670: this may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545437/how-to-disable-the-beep-in-emacs-on-windows/10545955#10545955

Comment: Emacs users normally abbreviate when referring to keyboard shortcuts.  For example, if someone is suggesting that you press `C-h`, what that really means is hold the `control` key down and (while holding the `control` key down) then press the letter `h`.  The combination `M-x` means press the `escape` key once and release it, and then press the letter `x` and release it.

Comment: User 17670: Please do start the built-in tutorial (it's in the Help menu). Your confusion over the standard key representations would be resolved in the opening few paragraphs, and working your way through the whole thing will will be invaluable for getting started with Emacs.

Answer (score 1):

(1) Emacs reads a number of init files, if they exists. The traditional file is named `~/.emacs`, i.e. it is named `.emacs` and it is placed in the root of your home directory. On Unix-like operating system (which Mac OS X is), a file starting with a dot is hidden when listing the content of the directory with the command `ls`. Nowadays, it is recommended to use the file `~/.emacs.d/init.el`, as this would allow you to archive the entire `.emacs.d` directory in a version control system.

(2) Yes, the content is assumed to be Emacs Lisp (or elisp, for short). The file is evaluated one lisp expression at a time. Normally, things can be placed in any order, as long they do not have anything to do with each other.

(3) The parentheses are a part of the list syntax. A function call is written like `(my-function argument-1 argument-2)`. In this case `load` is the function you call to load the file into Emacs. Often, of course, it's better to defer the actual loading of the file until it actually is used, you can do this with the function `autoload`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I still can't find the init file. In `~`, I have the `.emacs.d` file, but it only contains an empty folder called `auto-save-list` :S

Comment: @Drew I literally have no idea what that means. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: `C-h r g init file` is how to read the build in help. So first type `Ctrl`and `h` see what happens and add the other characters later...

Comment: @User17670, all you have to do is to create a new configuration file, just make sure you pick one of the names Emacs look for, like `~/.emacs.d/init.el`.

Comment: @User17670: You really need to start at the beginning, and learn at least basic Emacs key-sequence notation. What `C-h r g init-file` means is this: Press and hold the Control key while hitting the `h` key. Then hit the `r` key, then the `g` key. Then type `init file`. (And then hit the `Return` key.) That will show you exactly the part of the manual that explains what you are asking: node `Init File` of the Emacs manual.