# emacs customization on ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

hi im new to ubuntu and very very new to emacs I've installed them and happily editing files and doing all other things except for the emacs doesn't work for me the way it is supposed to. No syntax highlighting and code hinting and the awful color theme  is hurting my eyes please help me configure it have been searching for this on google for about 10-15 hours and ended up instructions like this that i dont even understand :

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "/path/to/color-theme.el/file")
(require 'color-theme)
(eval-after-load "color-theme"
 '(progn
    (color-theme-initialize)
    (color-theme-hober)))
```

Comment: Can you confirm you are using emacs 24 ? (help menu -> about emacs or Ctrl-h Ctrl-a)

Comment: the color-theme method is a bit old but still works. for emacs 24 we have `M-x load-theme`

Comment: Syntax highlighting for what exactly?

Comment: for editing php and c++

Comment: maniteja: [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545437/how-to-disable-the-beep-in-emacs-on-windows) should help you understand some of the essentials about customising Emacs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Add package repositories:

   ```
   (package-initialize)
   (add-to-list
    'package-archives
    '("marmalade" . "http://marmalade-repo.org/packages/"))
   (add-to-list
    'package-archives
    '("melpa" . "http://melpa.milkbox.net/packages/"))
   ```
2. <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-list-packages`.
3. Select some theme, e.g. `zenburn-theme` (you can use <kbd>C-s</kbd> to search for it).
4. Mark for install with <kbd>i</kbd> and execute install with <kbd>x</kbd>.
5. Test this in `*scratch*`

   ```
   (require 'zenburn-theme)
   ```
6. If you like it, add it permanently to `~/.emacs`, otherwise keep browsing
   the repositories.

Comment: i get the steps from 2 but the step 1 :/ i dont know what that means or where to add it? and thank you :)

Comment: Hi and welcome ! Some recommended reading: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/User's_Initialization_File which links to http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html#Init-File and about themes: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Themes

Comment: @abo-abo installed it but no joy

Comment: At which step are you?

Comment: thanx for helping brother i guess now it time to switch back to netbeans

Comment: What does it say when you press `x`?

Comment: FWIW --- I do not particularly recommend the Wikemacs post that @Ehvince recommends (but do take a look at it anyway). It is superficial and misleading, saying that `color-theme.el` "had some problems that we won’t be discussing here", and saying nothing about problems with custom themes.  Instead, or at least in addition, I recommend [this post](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ColorTheme) on Emacs Wiki -- it covers both color themes and custom themes, with some details about color themes instead of empty dismissal. For details about custom themes, see the Emacs manual.

Comment: The best source for info about your [init file](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/InitFile) and your [custom file](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CustomFile) is the Emacs manual.

Comment: Maniteja: don't give up ! it's not as difficult as you think. You may need some doc about the package system: http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Elpa (as @Drew pointed out, Wikemacs is less complete than emacswiki, but you'll still find very usefull stuff, and better organized).

Comment: I wasn't gonna give up until yesterday brother but its eating away all my time so had no choice and will surely try it again now @Ehvince

Comment: took some time reinstalled every thing and went thru all of your instructions and installed the package it worked the theme changes :) thank you all :D but it still doesnt do the syntax highlighting and auto completion like it does in netbeans IDE is there some other package ihave to install to do that?

Comment: Surely there has to be syntax highlighting. Emacs does this out of the box.
What's the file extension?

Comment: .php is the file extension

Comment: i've just now check it with cpp extension and works gr8 :D i love it but doesnt work for .php

Comment: I don't know php, but probably you should install `php-mode` from the repository just like you did before. If you get more issues with that, ask a new question.

Comment: Yes there is a `php-mode` in the packages. Also you may benefit from using Emacs Prelude, it's a very good Emacs configuration out of the box. http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Prelude and https://github.com/bbatsov/prelude

Comment: just installed it working gr8 im loving it thank you all