# Run some lines in emacs (amateur thing)

Tags: emacs

I'm supposed to run these lines in emacs. But, I don't know how. I don't know if I should compile, write it in a shell command, or what.
This is supposed to make an interface between a program called tidal, and emacs.

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "{directoryfile}")
(require 'haskell-mode)
(require 'tidal)
```

Comment: The type of stuff you are citing is normally placed inside the `.emacs` file -- the first time this is done, Emacs needs to be restarted.  You will need to install the `haskel-mode` and `tidal` libraries if you have not already done so.

Comment: You could also just paste these into the `*scratch*` buffer and evaluate them by typing `C-x C-e` or `M-x eval-buffer`.  (The former key-sequence evaluates just one balanced "form" before the cursor, the latter evaluates everything in the current buffer.)

Comment: To put that code into your init file (`~/.emacs`), start Emacs, then do `C-x C-f ~/.emacs` (that's `Control-x` `Control-f` `x`) to create an empty init file. Then type the code into the file, and save it using `C-x C-s`. Then restart Emacs and it will automatically pick up your new init file and evaluate the code you entered.

Comment: This Q&A often proves helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545437/how-to-disable-the-beep-in-emacs-on-windows

Comment: Note that your `{directoryfile}` needs be a path to a directory which contains Emacs libraries. Presumably the instructions you're following are assuming that `haskell-mode.el` and `tidal.el` are in that directory.

Comment: Welcome, new user.  Please have a look at the Emacs tutorial, which will get you started.  From within Emacs, type `Control-h t`.