# Windows emacs configuration

Tags: windows, emacs, scroll

I use emacs on a Windows computer (I can't chose another OS as it's my work computer).
I want a smooth scrolling but I can't find where to put the configuration file. I've read things like https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html but  that doesn't work. Does anyone know how to do it?
Thanks.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/a/10545955 help?

Comment: From this I found a way. Thanks.

Comment: All you need is `(setq scroll-conservatively 101)`.  The default of `scroll-step` need not be touched.  You'll find a zillion references on the internet to other settings, but they are not needed (in my opinion).  As I found myself always hitting the `recenter` command, I'm seriously considering modifying my dire-hard love of smooth-scrolling caused by years of commercial word processor use.

Answer (score 0):

You said you followed the instructions @ https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Windows-HOME.html but it didn't work. Did you try updating the system registry as suggested by https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/MS_002dWindows-Registry.html#MS_002dWindows-Registry? That is what worked for me.

I added GNU/Emacs to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SOFTWARE and added a string HOME with the directory I wanted emacs to refer to as home (C:\Users\my_user_name).

That same link will also describe the search order emacs uses and the values of Environment Variables you can set.