# GNU Emacs closing beginning/end of buffer sound

Tags: scroll, emacs24

I just started on GNU emacs, but I want to close the sound (windows not-allowed sound?) when I try to scroll end of buffer, or beginning of buffer. I searched options page (or prefereces) in emacs, I can't find it. Anyone know any solution (excepts closing speaker :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable the beep in emacs on Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10545437/how-to-disable-the-beep-in-emacs-on-windows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `(setq visible-bell t)` to your .emacs